# How to validate form in slot from parent component in vue?

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

### InfoItemComponent

```
<form action="" @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
  <div class="account-container_right__infoInput">
    <!-- <input type="text"> -->
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
  <div class="account-container_right__infoButtons">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary">save</button>
    <button class="btn btn--default" @click.prevent="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

### how i use InfoItemComponent

```
<info-item @formSubmit="formSubmit">
  <input type="text" v-validate="'required'" >
</info-item>
```

What I want to do is when I hit the submit button in infoitemcomponent, I want to validate the input element by vee-validate. How I can do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

> You have to emit an event in parent component when the form submitted and in parent component validate the inputs.

**InfoItemComponent:**

```
<template>
  <form action="" @submit.prevent="formSubmit">
    <div class="account-container_right__infoInput">
      <!-- <input type="text"> -->
      <slot></slot>
    </div>
    <div class="account-container_right__infoButtons">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn--primary">save</button>
      <button class="btn btn--default" @click.prevent="cancelEdit">cancel</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
    //other code..
    methods: {
      formSubmit() {
        this.$emit('formSubmited')
      }
    }
    //other code..
  }
</script>
```

**how to use InfoItemComponent**

```
<info-item @formSubmited="formSubmit">
  <input type="text" v-validate="'required'" >
</info-item>

<script>
 export default {
    //other code
  methods: {
    formSubmit() {
      //here validate your fields
    }
  }
   //other code
 }
</script>
```